# Verifing that two perpendicular vector fields on $S^{2n+1}$ commute.

Tags: differential-geometry

I am studying vector fields and i have been working on this problem that i can not solve. I would appreciate any idea or comment in case i am doing something wrong

The problem :

Let  $X: S^{2n+1}\to TS^{2n+1}$ a vector field defined by $ x \to ix $

a) Find the flow $\theta_t$ of the vector field X .

b) Let Y be a vector field defined on $\Bbb{CP^n} $ and Y´ a  vector field on $S^{2n+1} $ such that

$ Y´ \bot X $  and   $ d\pi(Y´) = Y$

Where $ \pi : S^{2n+1} \to \Bbb{CP^n} $ is the canonical projection $ x \to [x] $

Show that Y defines Y´.

c) Show that $\theta_{t*} Y´ = Y´  $

What i have got:

The flow $\theta_t (x) = xe^{it}$ .

b) finding the kernel of $d\pi_z$  i can see that Y' is determinated by Y decomposing the vectors fields in their orthogonal projections to X.

Ker$d\pi_z$ = {$i\alpha z, \alpha \in \Bbb{R} $}

c) Im trying to solve c) using b) so i have got to check  that $d\pi( \theta_{t*}Y) = d\pi(Y)$ . And here is where i don't know what to do, I can calculate $\theta_{t*}Y(z) = e^{it} Y(e^{-it}z)$ from the definition, but i am not able to see why they commute or how can i use the projective space for conclude.

Comment: Alicia, it takes a while to get used to the language of Differential Geometry. You are confusing $Y$ and $Y'$. From $d\pi(Y') = Y$, and the fact that $Y'$ is tangent to the sphere, and orthogonal to $X$, you can actually deduce that the vector field $Y'$ has the same value on flow orbits of $X$ (where as usual in $\mathbb{R}^{2n+2}$, one can compare values of vector fields at different points using the standard flat connection).